# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate ~500k docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As I want to update a whole collection of documents (some may exists, some not) with 500k entries, I loop over my docs (which are plain JS objects that come from a CSV) and update all my docs via `findOneAndUpdate` method.

Here is a simplified JS code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { mongoUrl } = require("../config.js");
const MyModel = require("../models/MyModel");

async function run() {
  mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
  await mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  const r = [/* */]; // <-- Something with 500k objects

  const total = r.length;
  for (let i in r) {
    const e = r[i];
    e.REF = e.REF.trim();
    await MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ REF: e.REF }, e, { upsert: true, new: true });
    if (i % 500 === 0) {
      console.log((i / total) * 100 + "%");
    }
  }
}

run();
```

First insertions are fast (more than 500 each second), but when it comes to 25%, it start to be really slow (10 seconds or more for 500 entries). I think it would be slower (frozen?) near 80%.

*Is there a better approach to do such a thing? How can I speed up things?*

I mean, it's only 500k entires (with a lot of properties, but I don't think it matters).

Comment: Do you have an index on `REF`? Otherwise the database will have to scan through the entire collection to figure out whether there is a model with that same REF.

Comment: @AKX Yes, of cou... Hum... Woops, no. Thank you! It's *far* better now. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. I feel dumb right now.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help!

Comment: I believe [Amit Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998875/8838398) is more complete if you want even more performance, so you may want to take a look at it. I provided an example of `.bulkWrite()` if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comment as answer:

Do you have [an index on `REF`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)? Otherwise the database will have to scan through the entire collection to figure out whether there is a model with that same `REF`.

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 ways you can do this more effective that i can think of.

1. make sure you have index on REF .
2. create batch updates instead of waiting 1 by 1 [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Answer (score 1):

I used to do these kind of operations for database model migrations, and I found out that `.bulkWrite()` really makes a difference here. What I would do is the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { mongoUrl } = require("../config.js");
const MyModel = require("../models/MyModel");

async function run() {
  mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
  await mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  const r = [/* */]; // <-- Something with 500k objects

  const total = r.length;
  // Set empty array of bulk write operations
  let bulkWriteOps = [];

  for (let i in r) {
    const e = r[i];
    e.REF = e.REF.trim();
    /* As every update operation is different because it depends on the iteration 
    variable, you have to push each element individually */
    bulkWriteOps.push({
        updateOne: {
            'filter': { REF: e.REF },
            'update': e,
            'upsert': true
            // As you are not using the result of the update, you don't need the new: true flag
        }
    })

    if (i % 500 === 0) {
      console.log((i / total) * 100 + "%");
    }
  }
}

if (bulkWriteOps.length) await MyModel.bulkWrite(bulkWriteOps)

run();
```

In your case, in every iteration you are *awaiting* for the document to be queried and updated. Bulk write was designed to avoid these kind of situations and let the DB do the hard work behind the scenes.

If you want to read more in depth about the topic, take a look at [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-executionofoperations), here it tells you about the batch size and order of operations.

Hope this somehow helps you with your issue